# Split contents of cells in dataframe by every character

Tags: python, r, perl, awk

What's the easiest way to split the contents of a dataframe so that every character can be separated from every other (which I think means things like strsplit wont work).

Say I have

```
> da
  V1  V2 V3         V4 V5   V6   V7       V8 V9    V10 V11 V12 V13    V14
1 TNVERI SMH EG ZSMRNPMUD:  M SLRN PYMP VERRNVPT  M ZSMRNP  PE PYN TQR THNNZT
V15   V16   V17 V18   V19   V20
1 EQP NXQMS MUNMT  LR NXQMS PLKNT
> dput(da)
structure(list(V1 = "TNVERI", V2 = "SMH", V3 = "EG", V4 = "ZSMRNPMUD:", 
V5 = "M", V6 = "SLRN", V7 = "PYMP", V8 = "VERRNVPT", V9 = "M", 
V10 = "ZSMRNP", V11 = "PE", V12 = "PYN", V13 = "TQR", V14 = "THNNZT", 
V15 = "EQP", V16 = "NXQMS", V17 = "MUNMT", V18 = "LR", V19 = "NXQMS", 
V20 = "PLKNT"), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", 
"V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

And I want to count how often every letter/character occurs, whether in a word or not. A solution in any language is fine.

Bonus: This is a cryptography puzzle. If anyone wants to see if they can figure out what this says in English, then show your work!

Comment: So for the first part, you are looking for a vector of characters that would be: c('T','N','V','E','R','I','S',...,'N','T')? And then the frequency of each letter?

Comment: the question itself is kind of "encrypted" for me... I cannot understand what do you have and what do you want to get.... :(

Comment: Solved the puzzle. I was apparently the 1156th person to do so. Link to the puzzle is here: http://blog.physicsworld.com/2013/10/03/physics-world-at-25-puzzle-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsplit` would work fine, if I understand your question correctly:

```
table(unlist(lapply(da, strsplit, ""), use.names = FALSE))
# 
#  :  D  E  G  H  I  K  L  M  N  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  X  Y  Z 
#  1  1  5  1  2  1  1  3 11 12  9  4  8  6  7  2  3  2  2  3
```

Comment: I like this. Splitting on everything with apply... Looks so simple when I see it! Thanks. Will be accepted when I can.